# Using a date as primary key with an aggregation table Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, datetime, primary-key, sybase, ase

I'm currently working on a Sybase ASE rdms and I have the following table (JOB_AUDIT) filled with sample dataset :

| IDJOB | BATCH | M_DATE | START_TIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | 40100 | 40110 |
| 2 | A | 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | 40111 | 40118 |
| 3 | B | 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | 40118 | 40129 |
| 4 | A | 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | 40100 | 40112 |
| 5 | A | 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | 40113 | 40118 |
| 6 | C | 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | 40120 | 40134 |

....

What I want to do is at first to calculate the total execution time for each batch to run on a daily basis, then I want to calculate the pencentage each bach took on the daily execution.

so I created this query :

```sql
SELECT
  T1.M_DATE as Batch_DATE,
  T1.BATCH as Batch,
  count(T1.IDJOB) as Nb_jobs,
  sum(T1.END_TIME-T1.START_TIME) as Exec_Duration,
  sum(T1.END_TIME-T1.START_TIME)/T2.total as pct
FROM
  JOB_AUDIT T1
inner join 
  (select M_DATE,sum(END_TIME-START_TIME) as total from AUDIT_REP group by M_DATE) T2
ON
   T1.M_DATE = T2.M_DATE
GROUP BY  T1.M_DATE,T1.M_BATCH;
```

the T2 table should give me an output like this :

| M_DATE | total |
| --- | --- |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | 28 |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | 31 |

then the final table should look like :

| Batch_DATE | Batch | Nb_jobs | Exec_Duration | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.607 |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | B | 1 | 11 | 0.393 |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.548 |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | C | 1 | 14 | 0.452 |

but it seems like the the join isn't working as I have the following result  :

| Batch_DATE | Batch | Nb_jobs | Exec_Duration | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.607 (17/28) |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.548 (17/31) not correct |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | B | 1 | 11 | 0.393 (11/28) |
| 12-25-2012 00:00:00 | B | 1 | 11 | 0.355 (11/31) not correct |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.607 (17/28) not correct |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 17 | 0.548 (17/31) |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | C | 1 | 14 | 0.500 (14/28) not correct |
| 12-27-2012 00:00:00 | C | 1 | 14 | 0.452 (14/31) |

So, I was wondering why I couldn't use a date a key, I'm sure there will always be a unique record per date in my T2 table as I grouped by date.

I thought the problem was that the record was a datetime to I even replaced all M_DATE fields by convert(date,M_DATE) and it changed nothing.

Note : I'm working with SYBASE ASE so I can't use window functions as it is not supported by this RDMS

Comment: where does `T1.M_BATCH` come from? did you mean `T1.BATCH`? this would be easier to address if you provided the DDL/DML for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem --

```
sum(t1.endtime-t1.start_time)/t2.total
```

--
I know you want to make the aggregation's result to divided with t2.total -- But the syntax here will take each matched line in t1 to sum first then divided with t2.total.
So if you write it to --

```
sum(convert(float,(t1.endtime-t1.start_time))/t2.total)
```

--
Then it will give you the result you want --
Here's my test--

```
1> select * from JOB_AUDIT
2> go
 id          batch m_date                          start_time  endtime
 ----------- ----- ------------------------------- ----------- -----------
           1 A                 Dec 25 2012 12:00AM       40100       40110
           2 A                 Dec 25 2012 12:00AM       40111       40118
           3 B                 Dec 25 2012 12:00AM       40118       40129
           4 A                 Dec 27 2012 12:00AM       40100       40112
           5 A                 Dec 27 2012 12:00AM       40113       40118
           6 C                 Dec 27 2012 12:00AM       40120       40134

(6 rows affected)
1> select * from T2
2> go
 m_date                          total
 ------------------------------- -----------
             Dec 25 2012 12:00AM          28
             Dec 27 2012 12:00AM          31

(2 rows affected)
1> vi
[sh:vi /tmp/ctisql_SCNCSP]
1> select t1.m_date,t1.batch,count(id) nb_jobs,sum(t1.endtime-t1.start_time) as Exec_Duration,sum(convert(float,(t1.endtime-t1.start_time))/t2.total) pct
2> from JOB_AUDIT t1, T2 t2
3> where t1.m_date=t2.m_date
4> group by t1.m_date,t1.batch
5> order by 1,2
6> go
 m_date                          batch nb_jobs     Exec_Duration pct
 ------------------------------- ----- ----------- ------------- ---------------------------
             Dec 25 2012 12:00AM A               2            17                    0.607143
             Dec 25 2012 12:00AM B               1            11                    0.392857
             Dec 27 2012 12:00AM A               2            17                    0.548387
             Dec 27 2012 12:00AM C               1            14                    0.451613

(4 rows affected)
```

Hope it help